# Accessing content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I would like to access the content provider using URI, which is of the following form.

```
sUriMatcher.addURI("org.abcd.providers.contentprovider", "bookmarks", 1)
```

So, can I access it using the URI, "content://org.abcd.providers.contentprovider/bookmarks" ? What does the value "1" mean? How do I query the provider of this type, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "1" is used internally in the ContentProvider. Its used to associate an URI with an number. Handy for using in a switch statement.

Why not using String matching? Well, an URI might have variable parts. For example "content://my.provider/bank/customer/2". The 2 is the Id of the customer. Or "content://my.provider/location/42/name". The variable part here is the 42. String matching goes out of control here. The UriMatcher on the other hand is able to match example 1 with addURI("my.provider", "bank/customer/#", 1) and example 2 with addURI("my.provider", "location/#/name",2). When we ask a configured UriMatcher to match a URI it returns the number associated with the matching URI.

But we are going out of track here. The number is not relevant to you as a consumer. You can query the provider with the context method 'getContentResilver().query(content://org.abcd.providers.contentprovider/bookmarks, /*other args */)'. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) for more infos.

But you can only talk to the provider if its exported (nothing you can do about it) or it requires permissions that your application has. This includes no permissions at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining!